# Change formatting of IPv6 address in Terraform

Tags: ipv6, terraform

I'm running into problems with DNS and ipv6 addresses with Terraform.  I'll get an address like 2345:0425:2CA1::0567:5673:23b5 from Digital Ocean, Vultr, etc.  That gets sent that to Constellix for the initial DNS record creation.  However, on ongoing runs, Constellix returns it without leading zeros like this: 2345:425:2CA1::567:5673:23b5.  That triggers Terraform to think it needs to be changed on every sync.

I can hardcode the ipv6 addresses in the Terraform file after initial creation but that isn't an ideal solution.

Any suggested fixes are appreciated.

Comment: Those are both valid ways of IPv6 addressing. _[RFC 4291, Section 2.2. Text Representation of Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.2)_ gives you three different conventional IPv6 text representations. _{RFC 5952}(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952)_ updates that to a single canonical IPv6 text representation, but requires accepting any of the valid conventional formats  but only outputting the canonical format. It sounds like the ones with leading zeroes are not following RFC 5952, but Constellix is following the RFC.

Comment: This suggests that one of the providers you are using (whichever one owns the resource type that is planning changes every time) is missing a normalization rule in its own logic. Part of the job of a Terraform provider is to provide rules for whether a difference between two values for an argument constitutes a meaningful change or just a different way of writing the same information. This provider seems to need a rule for treating all serializations of a particular IPv6 address as equivalent. I'd suggest opening a bug report with that provider.

Comment: Thanks @MartinAtkins I'll open bug reports with the providers and will reference RFC 5952 as per Ron Maupin.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting to Hexadecimal

```
format("%x", var.ipv6)
```

https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format#verbs

Comment: This was close.  I found an issue on Github with the following recommendation:  https://github.com/vultr/terraform-provider-vultr/issues/271:  
cidrhost("${address}/128", 0)

Answer (score 0):

Use cidrsubnet

```
cidrsubnet(var.ipv6_prefix, 0, 0)
```